# Replace values in row of a data.frame by values of corresponding row a vector

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, replace

I want to replace each value of a row of data.frame, for with a equal sized logical matrix has the value TRUE, by the value of a corresponding row of a vector. 
Here is an example:

```
> df1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    8    9    4
[2,]    2    6    6    6
[3,]    4    9    4    8

> a
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,] TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

> df2
[1] 5 4 6
```

So the result should look like this:

```
> df1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5    8    9    5
[2,]    4    6    6    6
[3,]    6    9    6    8
```

Is there any way to do this without the use of loops?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We replicate 'df2' by the `row` of 'a' or 'df1', based on the logical matrix of 'a', we change the value

```
ifelse(a, df2[row(a)], df1)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5    8    9    5
#[2,]    4    6    6    6
#[3,]    6    9    6    8
```

If it is `data.frame`, then we need to just change `as.matrix(df1`) and it should work in both cases

```
df1[] <- ifelse(a, df2[row(a)], as.matrix(df1))
```

---

Or another option is

```
(df1*!a) + (df2[row(a)]*a)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    5    8    9    5
#[2,]    4    6    6    6
#[3,]    6    9    6    8
```

NOTE:  Both the output are `matrix` as showed in the expected output and the initial dataset in the OP's example is `matrix`.  But it works with both `data.frame` and `matrix` (with the edit)

Answer (score 2):

You need some advanced subsetting for this:

```
df1[a] <- df2[row(a)[a]]
```

the output:

```
> df1
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  5  8  9  5
2  4  6  6  6
3  6  9  6  8
```

This solution works on both a dataframe or a matrix.